# Ejb timer task should run on every cluster member

Tags: java, timer, websphere, cluster-computing

I need an EJB timer task to run on every cluster member, instead of only one one of them.

Using WAS8 the timer service is configured to use an DB to store the data of persistent timers. It seems that all the persistent timers do run on only one cluster member. Is it true that the not-persistent timers will run on all the cluster members?

Comment: Does every cluster  node shares the same db of timers?

Comment: yes - they share the same db. So I believe this means they seem to be synchronized over the whole cluster, right?

Answer (score 1):

> yes - they share the same db.
> It seems that all the persistent timers do run on only one cluster member.

According to [documentation:](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Frejb_timerservice.html)

> Shared or common timer service database for the cluster. Timers can be created and accessed on any server process or cluster member. ... However, all timers are executed on a single server in the cluster, that is, the timeout method of the bean is run for all timers on a single server. Which server executes the timers varies depending on which server process obtains a lock on the common database tables.
>
> Is it true that the not-persistent timers will run on all the cluster members?

Non-persistence timers don't use the timer db, therefore, they will run independently in each cluster node. Note that every time the server is shutdown the non-persistence timers have to be created once the server start again.

Cluster issues are platform dependent, so a websphere tag could be added to your question.

Comment: I was able to find out, that with an "automatic non-persistent timer" (which is a timer created with the annotation @Schedule), it really does what I expected: it will call the callback method on all the cluster members. But it doesn't with a "programmatic non-persistent timer", which is being created during runtime in the Java code. In this case it runs only in the cluster member where it was created. This is unfortunately exactly the way I would need it right now - in a programmatic non-persistent timer. Maybe I'll find a way around it or someone may have a hint for me.

Comment: keep in mind, that the main difference between programatic and automatic timers is that the container gets the TimerService for you (the improvement of @Scheduled annotation is that you need write less code), I don't think this can change the behavior of timer.

Comment: Yes, it does change the behavior of the timer - according to IBMs documentation (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftejb_timerserviceejb_enh.html) and my analysis, programmatic times are supposed to run only on the VM where created. Automatic times (when nonpersistent) can run on all the servers in the cluster at the same time.